# Rails One to Many relationship with distinct exclusive status field for one model

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I am using Rails for this but it essentially is a SQL schema question.

I am creating a rudimentary inventory management database.

The schema currently is :

```
Shop

Inventory Pool

Inventory Item
```

Shops have a 1-Many relationship to Inventory Pool models.

Inventory Pools have a 1-Many relationship with Inventory Item Models.

The thing is. When a shop is created an associated Inventory Pool is created for that Shop that is designated as default. Right now the designation is only done in the name. But in terms of business logic i do not want the user to be able to delete it.

Now to make this default designation i could do it one of a couple ways.

I figured i could add a boolean flag to the Inventory Pool model. And basically when i create the initial default set that status to true.

When i want to change it to a different one I zero out the default fields in the association and then change it to the new one.

I can add a check in the `before_destroy` method of the `InventoryPool` model to prevent destruction if it is the default.

This will prevent the Shop from cascading destruction to the pools but i figured i can add a check to the before_destroy callback of the Shop class and zero out the defaults before hand.

I think that's simple enough.

---

The other option is to add an additional 1-1 between the `Shop` and `InventoryPool` models on top of the 1-Many which is explicitly the default.

The scenarios i'd have to handle all basically seem to relegate most of the logic to the Shop model rather than the InventoryPool. But doesn't that make sense?

I think i'm wrong but isn't the Default more of a Shop context specific field?

Anyway.... What is the best solution for handling a 1 to many relationship where there is a field of exclusive distinction on one of the records which must exist.

Model code below:

```
class Shop < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :inventory_pools
    has_many :inventory_items, :through => :inventory_pools

end

class InventoryPool < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :shops
    has_many :inventory_items

end

class InventoryItem < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :inventory_pools

end
```

Comment: so there basically is 2 different kinds of inventory pools, 1 that is a default that only can not be deleted and the shop only has 1 of, and the other that the shop can create and delete as needed?

Comment: subsequent question,  is the only difference between a default pool and the other pools that it can't be deleted?